# Problem during deploying Metabase with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, metabase

I am following this [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57973959/metabase-deployed-on-google-app-engine-doesnt-work) for deploying metabase with Google App Engine, after I complete the operations and open the url where the service is deployed i get ***502 Bad Gateway*** or
***Error: Server Error
The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.***  and from console I got
***INFO metabase.driver :: Registered abstract driver :sql  ?***
This is my app.yaml

```
env: flex

manual_scaling:
   instances: 1

env_variables:
   MB_JETTY_PORT: 8080
   MB_DB_TYPE: postgres
   MB_DB_DBNAME: metabase
   MB_DB_PORT: 5432
   MB_DB_USER: devops
   MB_DB_PASS: password 
   MB_DB_HOST: 127.0.0.1

beta_settings:
   cloud_sql_instances: <instance-name>=tcp:5432
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/openjdk

EXPOSE 8080

ENV PORT 8080
ENV MB_PORT 8080
ENV MB_JETTY_PORT 8080
ENV MB_DB_PORT 5432
ENV METABASE_SQL_INSTANCE <instance_name>=tcp:5432
ENV JAVA_OPTS "-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-modules=java.xml.bind"

ADD https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 ./cloud_sql_proxy
ADD http://downloads.metabase.com/v0.33.2/metabase.jar /metabase.jar

RUN chmod +x ./cloud_sql_proxy

CMD ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=$METABASE_SQL_INSTANCE=tcp:$MB_DB_PORT & java -jar ./metabase.jar
```

Also I troubleshoot everything I saw on stackoverflow and tried all options with similar problem but still not working, i tried this [option 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57973959/metabase-deployed-on-google-app-engine-doesnt-work) and this [options 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49778760/metabase-on-google-app-engine) but still no working effects.

My steps:
On GCP I am the owner of the project,I created Compute engine VM instance, then SQL Postgres instance, and a new Postgres database with user, I added the public IP address  of the VM in the configurations of the SQL Instance as authorized network, and deployed the app.yaml and Dockerfile with `gcloud app deploy`. Any working solutons?

```
  [1]: https://www.cloudbooklet.com/install-metabase-on-google-cloud-with-docker-app-engine/
```

Comment: I tried this https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/12549#issuecomment-638210783 And i got the following error: **Application startup error! Code: APP_CONTAINER_CRASHED
Start command: java -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-modules=java.xml.bind -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djavax.accessibility.assistive_technologies=
java.lang.Object -jar app.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile app.jar
**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue. I just change the metabase version, it always has to be the newest. 0.36.6 at this moment

Comment: I still have the issue even though I'm using the latest version, 0.39.3. Do you know what else might help?